# Type for intersection of all return types with list of functions

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Say I have an array of functions like so:

```
const foo: Array< () => object > = [
    () => ({ one: 'fish' }),
    () => ({ two: 'fish' }),
    () => ({ red: 'fish' }),
    () => ({ blue: 'fish' })        
]
```

Is it possible to write a type that will intersection the return types of all these functions?

```
{
  one: string,
  two: string,
  red: string,
  blue: string,
}
```

Basically, the type for what would result if you reduced all these functions into a single result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting problem. This can be done using a combination of mapped types and conditional types; we need to:

- Get rid of the type annotation `Array<() => object>` so that the array's actual contents can be used to construct a type,
- Get the function types from the array type,
- Get the return types of those function types,
- That gives a union like `{one: string} | {two: string} | {red: string} | {blue: string}` so we need to be able to get the property names (`keyof` doesn't work on a union like this),
- Get the value type associated with a given property name in the union,
- And finally, construct the result as a mapping from those property names to those value types.

Here's an implementation:

```js
const foo = [
    () => ({ one: 'fish' }),
    () => ({ two: 'fish' }),
    () => ({ red: 'fish' }),
    () => ({ blue: 'fish' })
];

type ComponentType<A extends any[]> = A extends (infer U)[] ? U : never

type ReturnsUnion = ReturnType<ComponentType<typeof foo>>
// {one: string} | {two: string} | {red: string} | {blue: string}

type KeyOfUnion<T> = T extends infer U ? keyof U : never
// KeyOfUnion<ReturnsUnion> = 'one' | 'two' | 'red' | 'blue'

type ValueInUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends { [k in K]: infer V } ? V : never

type Result = { [K in KeyOfUnion<ReturnsUnion>]: ValueInUnion<ReturnsUnion, K> }
// { one: string, two: string, red: string, blue: string }
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDaBYAUDXMAUAlCgHwEDeM4ApgFwwDkcAlhABYMwC+hANNngLFkZfJSgB3EPSasO3PgLxFSFGACdqAExkt2nHvxzLhoygCMANgFc6jPfJ7YAugG5s2KAE8ADtRgAwiAAtj40YFAAKr7UADwAgjDUAB5Q1GBaEDAAhmBeaM5kqIkpaRlZ+MxgcNTqMACqhAUwAPwNMPRg1AButR5Y3n4wAErUUNbqkPVgzOAoI2MTYNF+sUGh4VExsYPUIHDwiCQk2AD0pzDkNPTQ6lUA5lwwAD6XktIwtw9Pr+SaOp8oHcwI8XpcrLYbkDvv1djAANLULwAeTg01mYFikSKMEiSVS6UyMCqNTq9VaMAA1kj9u1Oj0+lhzgikaj0eBYqNxpMIOywDiGDROK8GO9hYx-uKGBDqAxYTEYAA1bI2agASTAfKxvAR+LKRIACuoQH51N5EV4cXjSoSspQ0JTiWAEc56CTakruBTFR0YF1eup5UNRhBrJZYKh7fCnSyUWiZhyuUteQn+a6lSrbBqtUmeXydfCyFwzhdKNdAcD7jr3lDKzr-rWHjqZY2QdxsEA)

Comment: Would it be possible to do this in a function?  IOW, the method would take an array of functions and return merged results?

Comment: nvm I see I can just make it generic.  Works like a charm! thanks